# Stop continuation of ASP.NET MVC ActionFilter

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, action-filter, actionfilterattribute

I have two custom ActionFilters on an action.

In first of the actionfilters, I have an redirect performed if a condition is not met (classic authorization). And in another I have an redirect performed if another condition is not met (say role checking).

But I do not want to continue to the second actionFilter if the first one is not met. How to do this?

Comment: This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9842910/2460971) on a similar question goes into more detail.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Setting the `filterContext.Result` property to any non-null value will stop execution of later filters.  So if your first filter sets `filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult(...)`, the second filter and action method will never be run.  This is how the built-in `[Authorization]` filter works.

Comment: I just had to go back into an MVC2 project, so leaving this here in case anyone still needs it:

If you want the normal functionality of `return null` in your Action, you can do `filterContext.Result = new EmptyResult();`