# How to skip action execution from an ActionFilter?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, action-filter

Is it possible to skip the whole action method execution and return a specific `ActionResult` when a certain condition is met in `OnActionExecuting`?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You can use filterContext.Result for this. It should look like this:

```
public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
{
    //Check your condition here
    if (true)
    {
        //Create your result
        filterContext.Result = new EmptyResult();
    }
    else
        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
}
```

Comment: Why do you skip base.OnActionExecuting when your condition is true? In my case I need that to run before I can set the Result.

Comment: @xr280xr that's just an example, the condition ay vary depending on your requirement.

Answer (score 36):

See my download sample and MSDN article [Filtering in ASP.NET MVC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg416513%28VS.98%29.aspx).

You can cancel filter execution in the `OnActionExecuting` and `OnResultExecuting` methods by setting the `Result` property to a non-null value.

Any pending `OnActionExecuted` and `OnActionExecuting` filters will not be invoked and the invoker will not call the `OnActionExecuted` method for the cancelled filter or for pending filters.

The `OnActionExecuted` filter for previously run filters will run. All of the `OnResultExecuting` and `OnResultExecuted` filters will run.

The following code from the sample shows how to return a specific `ActionResult` when a certain condition is met in `OnActionExecuting`:

```
if (filterContext.RouteData.Values.ContainsValue("Cancel")) 
{
    filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult("~/Home/Index");
    Trace.WriteLine(" Redirecting from Simple filter to /Home/Index");
}
```

Comment: It should be noted that if you have more than one filter and the order of the filters matters you should specify the "Order" parameter when registering your filter so you can control the execution order as Rick has outlined in his details about how the Result filterContext.Result property behaves.

Comment: Good point Nick - but see my section Filter Order - the order property only applies to filters in the same class. Auth always run first, exception, last.

Answer (score 4):

If anyone is extending `ActionFilterAttribute` in MVC 5 API, then you must be getting `HttpActionContext` instead of `ActionExecutingContext` as the type of parameter. In that case, simply set `httpActionContext.Response` to new `HttpResponseMessage` and you are good to go.

I was making a validation filter and here is how it looks like:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Occurs before the action method is invoked.
    /// This will validate the request
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="actionContext">The http action context.</param>
    public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        ApiController ctrl = (actionContext.ControllerContext.Controller as ApiController);
        if (!ctrl.ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var s = ctrl.ModelState.Select(t => new { Field = t.Key, Errors = t.Value.Errors.Select(e => e.ErrorMessage) });
            actionContext.Response = new System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage()
            {
                Content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(s)),
                ReasonPhrase = "Validation error",
                StatusCode = (System.Net.HttpStatusCode)422
            };
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following code here.

```
public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
 {
    ...
    if (needToRedirect) //your condition here
    {
       ...
       filterContext.Result = new RedirectToAction(string action, string controller)
       return;
    }
    ...
 }
```

RedirectToAction will redirect you the specific action based on the condition.

Comment: RedirectToAction is a method (at least in MVC5) so you can't new() it.

Comment: A worthless answer added long after the original (and correct) answers, and it's wrong as `filterContext.Result` must be a sub class of `ActionResult`. How this ever got up-voted is a mystery.

Answer (score 0):

I archived this as follows:

```
public void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
{
   if (!condition)
   {
      filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(
      new RouteValueDictionary{ { "controller", "YourController" },
                                { "action", "YourAction" }
                              });
   }
}
```

This will redirect you to the given action. Worked with MVC 4.