# convert asp.net webform to mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am very new to Asp.net MVC I have done before some Webform but things different here and I wounder How to implement master_page Page_Load event in asp.net MVC application and my code is like this:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   int intResult = 0;
   if (intResult != 0)
   {     
      Response.Redirect("url");
   }               
}
```

I want all my actions in a specific controller to go through this `if else` I want some thing more efficient than putting the `if else` in all my actions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create an actionfilter for your controller.

[Creating an action filter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd410056%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) and 
[How to prevent an action from executing from a filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9837180/asp-net-mvc-skip-action-execution-from-an-actionfilter).

**// Update**

In one of your comments I saw you want to redirect the user to the login page when he's not logged in. There's already something for that in ASP.NET MVC: The [Authorize attribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.authorizeattribute%28v=vs.118%29.aspx)

```
[Authorize]
public class MyController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

Comment: can you explain how this authorization work because my users are stored in a Database.

Comment: That's no problem. ASP.NET (both WebForms and MVC) has a Membership model that's used with authentication/authorization. By default you should use this, and this model abstracts the underlying storage medium away. The `Authorize` attributes plugs into this model as well by simply checking if a user is authenticated. See also http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2006/02/24/ASP.NET-2.0-Membership_2C00_-Roles_2C00_-Forms-Authentication_2C00_-and-Security-Resources-.aspx