# Prevent execution within Action Filter

Tags: asp.net-mvc, httpresponse, action-filter

I wish to create an Action Filter that checks that the user created some content.  If they don't, then I'd like to prevent the action from being executed and return an error.

This is what I have so far:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Http.Controllers;
using System.Web.Http.Filters;
using uQuiz.Domain.Abstract;
using uQuiz.WebUI.Helpers;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net;

namespace uQuiz.WebUI.Controllers.Filters
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Determines whether the current logged in user has permission to edit the quiz requested
    /// </summary>
    public class CanEditQuiz : ActionFilterAttribute
    {
        IQuizEntities Context;

        public CanEditQuiz()
        {

        }

        public CanEditQuiz(IQuizEntities context)
        {
            this.Context = context;
        }

        public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext actionContext)
        {
            // Get the URL ID from the request
            string urlId = actionContext.ModelState["urlId"].Value.ToString();
            int userId = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.GetUserId<int>();

            if (!QuizHelper.IsQuizOwner(this.Context, urlId, userId))
            {
                // Prevent action executing
            }

            base.OnActionExecuting(actionContext);
        }
    }
}
```

I've seen [other questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9837180/asp-net-mvc-skip-action-execution-from-an-actionfilter) mentioning to set `Result` to `null`, but when I overrode the `OnActionExecuting` method it has `HttpActionContext` and not `ActionExecutingContext` for some reason?

How do I prevent the action from executing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use

```
System.Web.Mvc.ActionFilterAttribute
```

not

```
System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute
```

Comment: Thank you, I changed my using statements and the override is now correct.